# Assigning Number to int

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently translating an application from actionscript-3 to Java code and got stuck with a variable assignment problem.

There is such block in as3 application:

```
var num:*=0;
...
num = 5.5;
```

As far as I understand AS3, variable is declared of an unknown type, which is resolved during the first assignment `=0` meaning it will become `int`. Am I right?

So does that mean that by assigning 5.5 to it, the Number will be converted to int, and I will have `num==5` in the result? Or will it become Number after assigning Number to it?

Thanks in advance.

**Added:**
Sorry, but I don't have any Flash environment to test it myself. I'm converting one of the utility methods from actionscript to Java and got stuck with this problem.

**Added 2:**
The question is, if num will contain `5` or `5.5` at the end of this block?

Comment: If the code in question is assigning a floating point number, I would assume double type in java.

Comment: @dwb: I added a clarification to the original post. The question is, if num will contain 5 or 5.5 at the end of this block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard datatypes for both integer and floating point data is `Number`. If you have `0` at the beginning, then it is a `Number`. Neither an int nor a double.

So, yes, the variable will contain `5.5` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing the number after second assignment, but I would guess that it will become Number.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any Flash environment to test it. I'm converting one of the utility methods from actionscript to Java and got stuck with this problem.